# How do I make a GTK3 image-in-a-window shrinkable?

Tags: c, gtk3

I have a simple GTK3 app that displays an image from a file in a window.
When you resize the window, the image is scaled in the expose callback to fit the window.

However, once the window has grown, you can't shrink it again; the resize handles only let you make the window ever bigger.

With GTK2 it was trivial to allow grow and shrink with gtk_window_set_policy(w,1,1,1).

How can the same effect be achieved in GTK3?

Here's the ever-growing code example:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h>

gboolean resize_image(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, void *data)
{
    GdkPixbuf *pixbuf = gtk_image_get_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(widget));
    if (pixbuf == NULL)
    {
        g_printerr("Failed to get pixbuf\n");
        return 1;
    }

    pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_scale_simple(pixbuf,
            widget->allocation.width, widget->allocation.height,
            GDK_INTERP_BILINEAR);

    gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(widget), pixbuf);

    return FALSE;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkWidget *window = NULL;
    GtkWidget *image = NULL;

    if (argc < 2 || argc > 3)
    {
        g_printerr("Usage: %s <image>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    image = gtk_image_new_from_file(argv[1]);
    if (image == NULL)
    {
        g_printerr("Could not open \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(image, "expose-event", G_CALLBACK(resize_image), NULL);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), image);
    gtk_widget_show_all(GTK_WIDGET(window));

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think `argc != 2` is easier to read than your expression

Comment: The trick is to use a `GtkScrolledWindow` around it and adjust the size of the image to that of the `GtkImage`. That is what works for me in Python :)

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion. It -er- sort of works but the scrollbars keep popping up and disappearing, and the image jiggles about as it is resized, sometimes getting left the correct size for the window, but with the scrollbars present which show that the image is centred on a larger white canvas tens of pizels larger in both directions. This seems to be the best that GTK3 can do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eric Cecashon on the gtk-list mailing list suggests using a cairo drawing area inside a 1x1 grid container, which works fairly well:

```
/*
    gcc -Wall da_resize.c -o da_resize `pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --cflags --libs`
    Tested on Ubuntu16.04, GTK3.18.
*/

#include<gtk/gtk.h>

gboolean draw_picture(GtkWidget *da, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data)
{
  gint width=gtk_widget_get_allocated_width(da);
  gint height=gtk_widget_get_allocated_height(da);

  GdkPixbuf *temp=gdk_pixbuf_scale_simple((GdkPixbuf*)data, width, height, GDK_INTERP_BILINEAR);
  gdk_cairo_set_source_pixbuf(cr, temp, 0, 0);
  cairo_paint(cr);

  g_object_unref(temp);
  return FALSE;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  GtkWidget *window=gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Resize Picture");
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 400, 400);

  g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  //Needs a valid picture.
  GdkPixbuf *pixbuf=gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file(argc>1 ? argv[1] : "image.jpg", NULL);

  GtkWidget *da1=gtk_drawing_area_new();
  gtk_widget_set_hexpand(da1, TRUE);
  gtk_widget_set_vexpand(da1, TRUE);
  g_signal_connect(da1, "draw", G_CALLBACK(draw_picture), pixbuf);

  GtkWidget *grid=gtk_grid_new();
  gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), da1, 0, 0, 1, 1);

  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), grid);
  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  g_object_unref(pixbuf);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still shocked at the hoops one has to jump through!

Comment: very similar app did not work for me before I found out that `'configure'` signal handler must return `FALSE`.